# Associated coverings of a right $G$-principal covering in tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, principal-bundles

The follwing are extracts taken from Tammo tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*, 2008 European Mathematical Society:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is the following:
I suppose that the category of G-sets contains the empty set, but for $F=\varnothing$, we have $E\times_G F=\varnothing$, so the associated "covering" map $p_F: E\times_G F \to B$ is not surjective (unless $B=\varnothing$); thus, it is not a covering map.

When defining locally trivial maps and coverings, tom Dieck says

> We assume that $p$ is surjective to avoid empty fibres.

Do we need to drop this assumption to obtain the desired functor?

Thank you in advance!